# How can I tell if a page is in print view?

Tags: javascript, printing

I'm using a simple toggle of the CSS `display` attribute from `none` to `block` in a FAQ page. However, I want the page to show everything when printing. What happens now is if you go to the page and go to print mode, it'll open all the closed items since I added this code to my print.css stylesheet...

```
.faq
{
    display:block;
}
```

However, if you open an item, close it again, and then go to print mode, that item will remain closed.

My JS code looks like this...

`    var divNum = new Array("faq1", "faq2", "faq3", "faq4", "faq5", "faq6", "faq7", "faq8", "faq9", "faq10", "faq11", "faq12", "faq13");

```
function openClose(theID) {
    for (var i = 0; i < divNum.length; i++) {
        if (divNum[i] == theID) {
            if (document.getElementById(divNum[i]).style.display == "block") { document.getElementById(divNum[i]).style.display = "none" }
            else { document.getElementById(divNum[i]).style.display = "block" }
        }
    }
}`
```

and the HTML looks like this

```
<a class="faq" onClick="openClose('faq1')">Question?</a><br />
<p id="faq1" class="faq">Answer</p>
```

What can I do to make sure everything is opened when I go into print mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of manipulating the display status of an element directly with your JS code, I would have classes defined in CSS then simply toggle the classes using JS.

If your classes are defined for @media screen only then you won't have to worry about what the current display status is of any of the FAQ entries.

EDIT: For example, in your CSS file:

```
@media screen .faq.open {
display: block;
}

@media screen .faq {
display: none;
}
```

Then your JS would look like:

```
function openClose(theID) {
    for (var i = 0; i < divNum.length; i++) {
        if (divNum[i] == theID) {
            if (document.getElementById(divNum[i]).className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)open(\\s|$)'))) { document.getElementById(divNum[i]).className = ele.className.replace(new RegExp('(\\s|^)open(\\s|$)'), ' '); }
            else { document.getElementById(divNum[i]).className += " open" }
        }
    }
}
```

Note, I haven't tested this so there may be some syntax errors.  Also, most of my projects already include jQuery so the method I typically use is much cleaner code.  I have not used jQuery here because you didn't use it in your code samples.

Comment: Well, that's what I thought too, but it doesn't seem to be working like that. I have the code `@media print {
    p.faq, span.faq
    {
        display:block;
    }
}` in both Site.css and Print.css and while it'll automatically open them if none of them have been altered by the JS function, if that happens, their print view is defined by their view on the page.

Comment: If you are still setting the display status using JS directly, it will override any styles defined in external stylesheets.  Doing object.display = 'none' is considered at the same cascade level as inline styles).  This is why I suggest toggling a class on the FAQ entry instead.  I'll update my answer with an example of what I mean.